# Creating a new element in javascript and tried the appendChild method to fit it... didn't work. What gives?

Tags: javascript, html, methods, element

guys. I created a new drop down menu inside my mock website I created. Everything's going fine EXCEPT an exercise I'm doing with vanilla Javascript. What I want to do is create an li element and then I do the same but create a new a element, the anchor for links. Here's what I have so far,

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
```

did the same for the anchor element.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
```

now I create a parent variable like this.

```
var parent = document.getElementById('ul-li-a').getElementsByTagName('li');
```

now I have an array of li's that get listed like this.

```
[li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li]
```

Here's where things get screwy for me. I then tried the append child method like so...

```
parent.appendChild(li);
```

only to get this bs error that stated exactly this.

```
Uncaught TypeError: parent.appendChild is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:8.
```

What exactly am I missing from this entire thing that I need to understand and implement?

Thanks in advance, everyone. :)

Comment: You'd usually want to append LI elements to a list (UL or OL).  So parent should probably be a reference to a list element.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `parent` is in this case a `HTMLCollection`. That is why the function `appendChild` is not defined. You have to apply the function `appendChild` to each element of this datatype. You can use this snippet (ES2015) to first convert it to an array and then use `forEach` to apply the function to all of the elements:

```
[...parent].forEach(x => x.appendChild(li));
```

or you can just iterate over the `HTMLCollection` (oldschool Javascript):

```
for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
    parent[i].appendChild(li);
}
```